# How to make an user login into a capsule in Samsung Bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am working on a Samsung Bixby Capsule which interacts with 3rd party site(X.com).
For example:
A user has an account in X.com now the user can login to his account using X.com credentials in Bixby Capsule.

I am aware that Bixby provides OAuth2 support. But I am unable to get a way how to set the credentials in `authorization.bxb` dynamically from user so that user wont have to enter credentials again for the next session.

I want the flow to be like:
User Triggers Capsule Login -> Bixby asks for Email and Password using form element -> Bixby utilizes those credentials to Login each time the user wants to perform an authenticated action.

As well if there is any way to hide the password in form element?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Does X.com have OAuth2 support?

If it does, you can hook that up with Bixby, and Bixby will handle the redirect to the login page and storage of tokens for you. And then you use those tokens to make OAuth2 HTTP calls from inside the capsule code.

See more examples of how to set up OAuth2 here: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.using-oauth

Is it not recommended to use a form element to input user passwords - that is why there is no way to hide input in the form element. And if you use Bixby's OAuth2, you won't need to worry about this issue at all.

Comment: No X.com does not have OAuth2 support. I am building an API to work as a middle-man for the authorization part. However, after token endpoint gets hit by bixby, it stills shows the login prompt in bixby.  Response of Token Endpoint:  {"access_token":"XXXXXXX","expires_in":3600}

Comment: I recommend reaching out to Bixby Developers support team for help with this. https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=360000286354